# Apache http server, Solaris 8

Tags: apache, solaris, weblogic-10.x

While starting the apache http server, I am getting the below error:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 67 of /isgwtld/lsam/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_wl_22.so into server: ld.so.1: httpd: fatal: relocation error: file /isgwtld/lsam/apache/modules/mod_wl_22.so: symbol unixd_set_global_mutex_perms: referenced symbol not found

Configuration used currently:

- OS: Solaris 8
- APACHE HTTP SERVER : 2.4.27
- weblogic: 10.3.0

Comment: Post the output from `ldd -rs /isgwtld/lsam/apache/modules/mod_wl_22.so`.

Comment: find object=libCrun.so.1; required by /isgwtld/lsam/apache/modules/mod_wl_22.so
    search path=/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/lib:/rap/app/sybase12/ASE-12_5/lib:/rap/app/sybase12/OCS-12_5/lib:/usr/lib:/rap/app/sybase12/SQLRemote/lib:/rap/app/sybase12/OCS-12_5/lib:/rap/app/sybase12/ASE-12_5/lib:/isgwtld/lsam/apache/lib:/isgwtld/lsam/apache/modules:/usr/local/lib/:/isgwtld/lsam/apache/modules:/opt/svn/1615/lib:  (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
    trying path=/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/lib/libCrun.so.1

Comment: Output is pretty large, it's trying to find some objects. Is there any other way I can contact you ?

Comment: Did you compile that module yourself or did you download it from somewhere?

Comment: Have compiled the module myself

Comment: @Anagha With what compiler?

Comment: @Andrew details are as follows:
Following dependencies for apache httpd-2.4.27 compiled with gcc version 3.2.2 
apr-util-1.6.0 
apr-1.6.2 
pcre-8.40
Installer name: apache_httpd-2.4.27-openssl-1.0.2l-src.tar.gz

Comment: @Anagha Given `find object=libCrun.so.1`, that means ` /isgwtld/lsam/apache/modules/mod_wl_22.so` was compiled with the Solaris Studio C++ compiler, to iuse the Solaris Studio C++ runtime.  You can't reliably use C++ modules that require another C++ runtime, such as those compiled with g++.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using an old version of the module or a mod_wl module compiled for an older httpd version (2.0 or 2.2).

In my case, I solved using an updated mod_wl version compiled for apache 2.4.